# Create Android SQL Database with a few pre populate data

Tags: android, sql, database, populate

I've gone through many examples here, but all seem complicated and most of them are for large data. I'm new to both Android and also SQL. What I want to do is just pre-populate my SQL database with some data.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE restaurants (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, address TEXT, type TEXT, notes TEXT, feed TEXT, lat REAL, lon REAL);");

    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put("name", "Hi");
    cv.put("address", "There");
    cv.put("type", "delivery");
    cv.put("notes", "");
    cv.put("feed", "");
    cv.put("lat", "");
    cv.put("lon", "");
    getWritableDatabase().insert("restaurants", "name", cv);
}
```

There is no error but unfortunately no data is inserted as well. This should be very simple, please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is fine, inside `SQLiteOpenHelper#onCreate()` is the right place to put initial data since that is where you create the database in the state you like it to be.

But inside `onCreate` you use `db.insert("restaurants", "name", cv)` directly. You are not finished to create the writable database you try to get via `getWritableDatabase()` at that point. Not sure if that is the problem but it could be.

Comment: i tried to use     db.insert("restaurants", "name", cv) directly, no error but still no data inserted. any other recommendation i could try? TQ.

Comment: sorry it works, i cleared and deleted the app on emulator, restart again, data is there. Thanks!

Comment: yes, `onCreate` is only executed if the database file does not exist. Once it does and you just reinstall / update your app `SQLiteOpenHelper` assumes that the existing file is correctly created. You would use the `onUpgrade` mechanism is you want to change the database state later.

Answer (score 2):

Use db.insert("restaurants", "name", cv);

Comment: i tried to use db.insert("restaurants", "name", cv) directly, no error but still no data inserted. any other recommendation i could try? TQ.

Comment: sorry it works, i cleared and deleted the app on emulator, restart again, data is there. Thanks!

Comment: Its ok mate.. happy to help you :)